# How can I find out where a script is loading twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, instafeedjs

I have a website that I'm using instafeed.js on which is a script that hooks into Instagram's API's and displays pictures in HTML/CSS. I only put this script in once but for some reason it's loading it and any changes I make twice. If I take my  tag out or remove the instafeed.js file, it doesn't load at all.

I'm still learning with javascript and I can usually figure these problems out through trial and error, but the site is loading 30+ scripts and quite frankly I'm out of ideas... What could be causing this and how can I find out?

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
 var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: '',
    clientId: '',
    accessToken: '',
    template: '<div id="{{id}}" class="instagram_container"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" title="{{caption}} by @{{model.user.username}}"><img src="{{image}}" alt="{{caption}} by @{{model.user.username}}" class="instagram_image" /></a></div><div class="instagram_image_meta"><div class="owner instagram_image_meta_item"></div><div class="caption instagram_image_meta_item"><p>{{caption}}</p></div></div>',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    limit: '30'
});
feed.run();
// ]]></script>
```

.. the page in question is over at https://www.bearbuttteam.com/pages/instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate Instafeed twice

[image]

Comment: I still don't understand what the source of this is - I understand that it shows up twice in HTML but I can promise it's only in one spot. I believe there's a script that's duplicating it and I'm not sure how to go about finding out which one it could be